# Namespaces used for test in official exemple don't work for me

Tags: php, namespaces

I have been trying to dowload the GraphQL version of PHP at this link: https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php (I git cloned then used "composer require webonyx/graphql-php")

But when I tried to execute the code included in the "test" folder, I kept getting mistakes for class "..." not found

I first tried launching this example (GraphQLTest):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace GraphQL\Tests;

use GraphQL\Executor\Promise\Adapter\SyncPromiseAdapter;
use GraphQL\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ObjectType;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use GraphQL\Type\Schema;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use function sprintf;

class GraphQLTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testPromiseToExecute() : void
    {
        $promiseAdapter = new SyncPromiseAdapter();
        $schema         = new Schema(
            [
                'query' => new ObjectType(
                    [
                        'name' => 'Query',
                        'fields' => [
                            'sayHi' => [
                                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                                'args' => [
                                    'name' => [
                                        'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                                    ],
                                ],
                                'resolve' => static function ($value, $args) use ($promiseAdapter) {
                                    return $promiseAdapter->createFulfilled(sprintf('Hi %s!', $args['name']));
                                },
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ),
            ]
        );

        $promise = GraphQL::promiseToExecute($promiseAdapter, $schema, '{ sayHi(name: "John") }');
        $result  = $promiseAdapter->wait($promise);
        self::assertSame(['data' => ['sayHi' => 'Hi John!']], $result->toArray());
    }
}
$t = new GraphQLTest();
$t->testPromiseToExecute();
```

It's just the test, but I added a line at the end to launch the function

But I got error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in C:\Users\antoine\Desktop\boulot\Graphql\php\graphql-php\tests\GraphQLTest.php:15
```

The program doesn't know PHPunit, so i reinstall it in the parent folder, the current folder, nothing works.

As a last resort, I modified the test to transform it into this code that doesn't use phpunit:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace GraphQL\Tests;

use GraphQL\Executor\Promise\Adapter\SyncPromiseAdapter;
use GraphQL\GraphQL;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ObjectType;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use GraphQL\Type\Schema;
use function sprintf;

class GraphQLTest
{
    public function testPromiseToExecute() : void
    {
        $promiseAdapter = new SyncPromiseAdapter();
        $schema         = new Schema(
            [
                'query' => new ObjectType(
                    [
                        'name' => 'Query',
                        'fields' => [
                            'sayHi' => [
                                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                                'args' => [
                                    'name' => [
                                        'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                                    ],
                                ],
                                'resolve' => static function ($value, $args) use ($promiseAdapter) {
                                    return $promiseAdapter->createFulfilled(sprintf('Hi %s!', $args['name']));
                                },
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ),
            ]
        );

        $promise = GraphQL::promiseToExecute($promiseAdapter, $schema, '{ sayHi(name: "John") }');
        $result  = $promiseAdapter->wait($promise);
        echo $result->toArray();
    }
}
$t= new GraphQLTest();
$t->testPromiseToExecute();
```

But I still get an error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GraphQL\Executor\Promise\Adapter\SyncPromiseAdapter' not found in C:\Users\antoine\Desktop\boulot\Graphql\php\graphql-php\tests\GraphQLTest.php:18
```

This is a tested release, the namespaces should not cause problems. I didn't change anything in these folders, how on earth are they not recognized? I had similar problems yesterday too when trying (unsuccessfully) to install GraphQLite.

I'm guessing my setup isn't good, thus making namespaces behave strangely, but I have no idea how to check that.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you `include`ing those classes somewhere, or do you `include` an autoloader that would include them for you…?

Comment: I'm only using the code provided without changing much, if the original GraphQLTest isn't using includes, I figured the "use" was supposed to be enough. I tried putting spl_autoload_register at the top of it, but it just created more problems, as trying to include the namespaces doesn't seem possible?